# SAPUI5 Load Table Row Values on Row Click on Same View

Tags: xml, sapui5, jscript, sap-fiori

I have created a simple view, with a table and some textbox controls.
I am trying to load the row values on row click in the text boxes below,
can anyone suggest, how to achieve this functionality.
Below is my view design, top of view is displaying filters for the table,
table is binding against the filters correctly,
Now I am stuck in a challenge, that on row click even, I am trying to bind row elements in textboxes boxes and dropdowns below. and reprocess my business process. But I am un able to do it,
( I cannot implement Navigation here as per clients requirement).

[image]

Thanks,
Regards,
Hamdan

Comment: posting the code for the above problem would highly help to give a solution.

Comment: Are you sure you have a Ui5 application ? This looks like a web dynpro application.

Comment: yes, I am moving a webdynpro to the UI5 view,

Answer (score 0):

are you related with the concept of element binding?
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f05e8b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070